# Connecting Laravel to Sqlite in Laravel 5.2

Tags: sqlite, laravel

How can I connect to Sqlite db?

I have done the below things

1) Created project.
2) Created database.sqlite inside the database folder (database\database.sqlite).
3) Changed 'default' => env ('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), to 'default' => env ('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'), in the database.php file.
4) Ran php artisan migrate.

But I am getting an error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Database (sqlite) does not exist.
```

Then I tried DB_DATABASE=database\database.sqlite as stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database) but I get the following error.

```
[PDOException]
Could not find driver
```

I have set the .env file as below

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: do you define your DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD?

Comment: i mean, can you go to your sqlite by username:homestead and password:secret

Comment: Yes, I have defined DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD

Comment: Yes I can go to sqlite using username:homestead and password:secret

Comment: do you configure the 'default' key in app/config/database.php?

Comment: Yes. I have configured.

Comment: Use the phpinfo function to list out the extensions installed and enabled. Is PDO existed and enabled there?

Comment: It seems Sqlite is available for the CLI, but not for PHP I need to install  sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite it seems. Please wait I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite is available for the CLI, but not for PHP. You need to install it. 
Run the below command in terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

If you're running php7, you need to install php7.0-sqlite.
After that restart your apache or whatever web server you have.